# Organic metallic compound

Tags: xenobiology, biochemistry, bio-mechanics

My organism have a weight of 270 kilograms. It have height of 2.49 metres. My organism is reptile and it lived in animals with metallic shells . My organism has bite force enough to crush car in single bite.  What metallic organic compound is it teeth and jaws bones reinforced to do so ? What mechanism does it use to produce this bite force ?

Comment: Some more details could be useful to help with this. How big is your creature? What is its natural environment like?

Comment: 2.49 m height and 270 kg weight . It's natural environment is like  trex lived environment

Comment: @Uuuuuuu You can [edit](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/231590/edit) the question at the bottom of it to add this data. Comments are often skipped, so it's not the best place for important information ^^. Regarding your question, it seems all your sentences end with a question mark "❓". Can you confirm that "My organism has bite force enough to crush car in single bite" is not actually a question? Also, it's generally helpful to precise what your creature is like : Big lizard, monkey, super-ant, etc... It helps in focusing the answer to the general theme of your best beasty :).

Answer (score 3):

May I introduce you to the [humble limpet](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limpet), who has already beaten this monster to metallic teeth.

Perhaps this monster is some distant descendent of the limpet or mad science has modified some T-Rex like animal to have this feature. Either way, metallic teeth and amazing bite force has already been done by mother nature. The challenge, which has been solved by this monster, is combining the two.

Cars are actually quite fragile things. Deer, moose, and bison can already dent and break them. For a creature the size of a T-Rex, breaking glass and tearing a car apart (enough) to get at the protein snacks inside should be a fun project.

Answer (score 1):

There is a quite a lot of work in paleontology where people take a look at skull and teeth shapes and calculate bite forces. The shape of the teeth are also evolved depending on the diet plant vs meat eaters and the way predators hunt. There are also people who study how and why teeth are grown and are as hard and tough as they are and look at the materials composition. All of these things are driven by the evolutionary pressures of how the animal grazes or hunts in their environment, so there seems to be be a big question as to why would your creature want to crush a car in a single bite.

1. The shape of a tooth - puncturing vs grinding, slicing vs holding you can have a much larger force in a smaller area with a pointed tooth, that can punch through and hold prey, but that is not as good for crushing and grinding.
2. The way the jaw makes a lever and provides mechanical advantage and the way the muscles are attached to the jaw to apply that force. For examples some animals have muscles that go from the jaw to over the top of the head to help provide more force.
3. A lot of ceramics are harder and less ductile than metals, but you can also structure materials in ways that make them very tough. For example shells are calcium carbonate, that is not that tough or hard of a material, but the way the shell is structured on the microscopic level with lots of little layers makes it very hard and tough, so you could have a inter-layered metal organic structure. If you want to have all metal or largely pure metal and have it be science based, then it seems like you more of a constructed creature, rather than an evolved one.
4. How is the prey digested - what goes through the gut and out the other end? This also is connected to how the teeth are shaped.

Hyenas are interesting predators, that have a very strong jaws since they crush the strong leg bones to get at the marrow inside. Saber tooth cats are interesting becasue the puncturing and holding aspects. Then of course dinosaurs and sharks...